# Dagger injected objects that create other dagger injected objects n levels deep and wide

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

How should one approach dagger injecting an application that's setup like so:

```
Root that creates:
|- LevelOneA
|  |- LevelTwoAA
|  |- LevelTwoAB
|  L  ....
|
|- LevelOneB
|  |- LevelTwoBA
|  |- LevelTwoBB
|  L  ....
|
L  ...
```

Each class has its own dependencies, and creates objects that has its own dependencies, which in turn creates objects that has its own dependencies, ad infinitum, etc. In essence, every object at every level needs some awareness of the dependency graph/injector such that they can inject themselves and ensure their children can be injected.

The most basic solution seems to be to just pass in the injector through the constructor of every object (such that each object injects itself, and passes the injector to its children to inject themselves). However, this doesn't seem quite right?

Additionally, this injector knows how to inject everything, so when testing and creating mocks, I would have to have mock out all the dependencies for LevelTenXYZ even if I'm testing an unrelated object.

Comment: Is there a reason why plain constructor injection is not an option?

Comment: Would it work to just inject a `Provider<LevelNXY>` or `Lazy<LevelNXY>` at all levels? Both are available for each binding in the graph, automatically, and can be simulated in tests.

Comment: `@Inject public MyConstructor(Dep1 dep1, Dep2 dep2, ...) { this.dep1 = dep1; ...}` if you have scopes, then the scope goes on the top of the class.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak @EpicPandaForce I'm already familiar how to use constructor injection. That doesn't seem to really answer the question on its face though? Maybe I'm missing something, but the problem is if I have `public MyConstructor(D1 d1, D2 d2, Injector injector)`, then how would you test this? It implicitly becomes dependent on all dependencies in the graph, and mocking Injector becomes a nightmare.

Comment: @JeffBowman If I'm reading you correctly, the idea would be for object `LevelN-1` be injected with a `Provider<LevelN>`, so whenever I needed to create an object of `LevelN` from within `LevelN-1`, I would just ask the provider to create one for me? Presumably the provided object of LevelN would just automatically come with a `Provider<LevelN+1>?

Comment: @DavidLiu the idea is that if every dependency is there, you do not have to pass the "injector" around, which is an anti pattern by itself. I always like linking to [Google Clean Code talks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0) which does a fantastic job on explaining the concept. You can just request dep1 and dep2, if they themselves can be constructor injected.

Comment: When Dagger (or Guice) injects a T or `Provider<T>`, it comes to you with all its dependencies injected already. If you have a "main object" that uses injection, you shouldn't need your injector or Dagger component implementation except to get that first main object. Everything after that comes from objects injecting other objects or providers.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak That's not really a helpful explanation to be honest. Request deps from who? The dependency graph right? Ok, so the root has access to the dependency graph since someone's gotta know it. So when L1 Object gets created by root, where is it going to get its dependencies from? Ok, maybe the root can supply it, but now the root has to have knowledge of Level1's dependencies. But L1 creates L2, which has other dependencies, so L1 needs L2's dependencies, and thus Root needs to know L2's dependencies to supply L1 with those as well. So on and so forth. That seems highly unreasonable.

Comment: You think about the creation of your objects in your objects. Stop doing that. Dagger creates your objects, you just tell it what you need. If ClassA needs ClassLevel2 then you put that in your constructor and let dagger worry where the object comes from. If it can't find it, you will get a compile time error anyways. The same for level 2, 3, etc. Put the things you need in the constructor and make sure everything they depend on is available on the graph, and dagger will create the objects, passing them to your constructors where needed. And the video does explain this also in good detail

Comment: @DavidMedenjak ClassRoot doesn't need a ClassL2 though. It outputs ClassL2s, based on the outputs of root's deps. I need to make new instances of ClassL2s, not just something given to the constructor. If dagger can make those new instances for me on demand, great. Explain how, as `public L1(D1 d1, D2 d2, L2 l2)` doesn't exactly level room for outputting an arbitrary number of L2 objects. If you're just talking about what JeffBowman stated above, injecting Provider<L2> so that I can obtain new L2 objects, let me know.